# conversion of matlab code to opencv code

Tags: c++, matlab, opencv

I have a matlab code in which the image x has 512*512 size were M=512 and N=512 next step is this

```
 r=x(:, 2:N) - x(:, 1:(N-1));
 d= mean2(abs(r(:, 8:8:8*(floor(N/8)-1))));
 a= (8*mean2(abs(r)) - d)/7;
```

Now I have to convert this steps in to opencv code so I am stuck with logic

```
 cv::Mat scrImage =imread(argv[1],CV_LOAD_IMAGE_ANYCOLOR); // Read the file 
 cv::Mat dst(scrImage.size(),CV_64FC3);//Image double
 int nrows = dst.rows;
 int ncols = dst.cols*dst.channels();
 for(int j=0;j<nrows;j++){
 for(int i=0;i<ncols;i++)
 {
}}
```

Any idea on this? Thanks in advance

Comment: Sorry your question is completely unclear, even for the [tag:matlab] and [tag:opencv] gurus around here I'm afraid.

Comment: sorry,i edited the question with clear explanation could you help me out now

Comment: Why did you accept the answer if it didn't help you? Or did it? It's a bit late for reopening this question. You may ask a different one, but take care to make it different enough to this question, otherwise it will be easily closed as duplicate.

Comment: i am very sorry for editing it.actually the below answer is partially correct.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are many ways to do this. Most clean way would be setting ROI (Region of Interest) and then applying matrix operations. Something like:

```
subtract(x(Rect(1,0,NumCols-1,NumRows)),x(Rect(0,0,NumCols-1,NumRows),R)
singleLineMask = Mat(1,NumCols,CV_8U)
for (int i=1;i<NumCols;i++)
    singleLineMask.at<int>(1,i)=1;
repeat(singleLineMask,NumRows,1,MaskImage)
d=mean(R,MaskImage)
a=(8*mean(abs(R))-d)/7
```

assuming you create R and compute NumRows,NumCols prior to this operation and allocate MaskImage.

Comment: Given the constructor for a Rect is `Rect_(_Tp _x, _Tp _y, _Tp _width, _Tp _height)`, and OpenCV uses 0 based indexing rather than Matlab's 1 based, shouldn't that be `subtract(x(Rect(1,0,NumCols-1,NumRows)),x(Rect(0,0,NumCols-1,NumRows),R)`?

Comment: sorry,i edited the question with clear explanation could you help me out now

Comment: My answer is still correct, I will edit according to your changes but you just added more lines. You do not need to use that logic

Comment: Why you have taking singleLineMask = Mat(1,NumCols,CV_8U), rows=1 and singleLineMask.at<int>(1,i)=1 why it is equall to 1.